# Ocaml isn't recognizing List.init in Utop

Tags: ocaml, opam

Anytime I use `List.init` I get the error `Error: Unbound value List.init`
I think this is because I have Ocaml 4.03.0 and `List.init` wasn't introduced until 4.06.0. This would lead me to believe that I need to update my ocaml version, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do this. I've tried many opam options, but nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 1):

With opam you don't upgrade the compiler, but rather install or switch to another compiler installation. That way you can juggle several different installations with separate sets of compatible packages.

You can print a list of available compiler versions by invoking

```
opam switch list-available
```

or to reduce it to only the official releases:

```
opam switch list-available base-compiler
```

Install a specific version, say `4.06.0`, by invoking

```
opam switch create 4.06.0
eval $(opam env)
```

Comment: I tried that and got this error `opam switch create 4.06.0
opam: Invalid switch subcommand "create"
Usage: opam switch [OPTION]... [COMMAND] [ARG]...`

Comment: you might have an old revision of opam - `opam switch create` is available with opam 2.0

Comment: Before 2.0 it was just `opam switch 4.06.0` and `eval $(opam config env)`, but you really should upgrade opam anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`List.init` is available from the janestreet `Core` module, it is not available from the standard library. You have to install `core` ; it is independent of the ocaml compiler.

```
 opam install core
```

In `utop` (Welcome to utop version 2.3.0 (using OCaml version **4.03.0**)) :

```
 utop # #require "core";;
 utop #  Core.List.init;;
 - : int -> f:(int -> 'a) -> 'a list = <fun>
```